# HTML parsing and method calling

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios

updated:
How many ways are to parse HTML in iPhone and how to call a method using javascript.
any link will appreciable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why you cannot use post request ? and what language are you working on. ? which website you are referring to ?

Comment: its complected, but its client requirement that i need to use this website html page only.

Comment: @GauravShah, to be fair, it does answer one of your questions.  If "cannot use post" is a client requirement, then he can't use post.  OP, it would still be useful to tell us what language you're intending to work in, and, if possible, what site you are intending to support.

Comment: even if he uses that site.. at the end of the day its going to be a post request.. So I wanted to know what he precisely means by a post request . judging by his explanation it seems he is not well versed with what a post is ..

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the page in a `UIWebView` and after the loading is completed on the page you need to do stuff with some Javascript like:-

```
[WebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:strCode];
```

Where strCode will be Javascript code to click the button

```
NSString *strCode = @"document.getElementById('submit').click()";
```

or you can change the values of the text fields

```
NSString *strCode = @"document.getElementById('textfield').value = 'Hello World'";
```

Answer (score -1):

Would it be a possibility to load the external page in an iframe and then use Jquery to extract the fields?